# What is the implicit ordering of a LIKE condition?

Tags: sql-server, like

I would like to know how the `LIKE` operator is classified, I have a query where I have a number of chained `LIKE` statements. How are the results from the following prioritized when they're returned?

```
AND (
  ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Address%'
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Email%' 
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Phone%' 
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Bank%'
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Number%'
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%NAME%'   
  OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Postcode%'
```

Just to add more clarification, as I think some people may have not entirely understood my question, I will show an example :

Let's say I'm looking for address (not emails) and I use the following statement:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC
    where ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Address%'
```

This is what I'm getting back:

[image]

I do the same with the following code:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS IC
    where ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Email%' 
    --OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Email%'
```

then I get back this:

[image]

This means that in the first case I'm getting back Addresses and Email Addresses. I know that they are just strings, but how can I get to search for Addresses and not get back email addresses like *email_address1*, *address_email1*, *web_Address_email* etc. I don't want to use the `where Column_Name = 'Address'` because that means I will miss out on different names such *Address1*, *Address2* etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects, you should use the SQL Server views, such as `sys.objects`.

For example:

```
SELECT s.name
    , o.name
    , c.name
FROM sys.schemas s
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON o.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'Address%'
    OR c.name LIKE 'Email%';
```

Note in the `WHERE` clause above, I have `LIKE 'Address%' OR LIKE 'Email%'`?  That is a logical OR operation, where column names can be anything that starts with Address or Email.

If you create a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable
(
    AddressLine1 varchar(100) NOT NULL
    , EmailAddress varchar(256) NOT NULL
);
```

And run the query above, you see the following results:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ name ║   name    ║     name     ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ dbo  ║ SomeTable ║ AddressLine1 ║
║ dbo  ║ SomeTable ║ EmailAddress ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

---

`LIKE` matches the content of a string against another string, usually using wildcard characters to match any unknown combinations of characters.

So, for example, if you have a column containing the following data:

```
╔════════╗
║ fruit  ║
╠════════╣
║ orange ║
║ apple  ║
║ grape  ║
║ banana ║
║ pear   ║
╚════════╝
```

And you run a `LIKE` comparison against it:

```
WHERE fruit LIKE '%ap%'
```

You'll get the following rows listed:

```
╔═══════╗
║ fruit ║
╠═══════╣
║ apple ║
║ grape ║
╚═══════╝
```

If you need only rows where the column values begins with "apple", you'd need to use:

```
WHERE fruit LIKE 'apple%'
```

In the above example, the wildcard, `%`, only appears at the end of the word `apple`, indicating we'll accept matches that *start with* `apple`.

If we run this:

```
WHERE fruit = 'apple'
```

We *only* get rows where the *entire* column value is equal to `apple`.

If you want all results that contain the two letters `ap`, but you want to exclude `grape`, you could do this:

```
WHERE fruit LIKE '%ap%' 
    AND fruit <> 'grape'
```

If you want all data with `ap` anywhere in the word, but nothing that starts with `gra`, you could do this:

```
WHERE fruit LIKE '%ap%'
    AND NOT (fruit LIKE 'gra%')
```

The `LIKE` operator does not *prioritize* its results.  It simply returns *all* rows that match the result.

From the [Microsoft Docs for the T-SQL LIKE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Determines whether a specific character string matches a specified pattern. A pattern can include regular characters and wildcard characters. During pattern matching, regular characters must exactly match the characters specified in the character string. However, wildcard characters can be matched with arbitrary fragments of the character string. Using wildcard characters makes the LIKE operator more flexible than using the = and != string comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your Logic for your `WHERE` clause

1. Is `Email_Address` like `%Address%`?  true
2. Is `Email_Address` like `%Email%`? true
3. Is `Email_Address` like `%Phone%`? false
4. Is `Email_Address` like `%Bank%`?  false
5. Is `Email_Address` like `%Number%`? false
6. Is `Email_Address` like `%NAME%`? false
7. is `Email_Address` like `%Postcode%`? false

Is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 true? true

That row is matching on both `%Email%` and `%Address%`.

If you don't want `Email_Address`, then you need to tell the database that you want rows `ic.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('Email_Address')`.

Comment: But what if I have similar type of fields(100s lets just say) with this type of issue ,does that ,mean I have to do this ` ic.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('Email_Address')`  for all of them? Is there a way where I don't know the all the column names and want to avoid this issue ?For example having `Email_Address1,Email_Address2,Email_Address3`

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing two things:

- Selectivity
- Priority / Order / Ranking

In SQL, 100% of *selectivity* is determined by conditionals (typically in `WHERE` and `JOIN`-clauses). And, 100% of *priority* is determined by `ORDER BY` without which the result is unordered. **In your case the result is unordered -- the order is undefined.**

```
AND (ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Address%'
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Email%' 
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Phone%' 
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Bank%'
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Number%'
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%NAME%' 
OR ic.COLUMN_NAME like '%Postcode%' ...
```

All of that is collapsing into a single conditional to add absolute selectivity,

```
AND ( sometimes )
```

Whatever that `sometimes` is, is either absolutely *satisfied* by the result (row in question) or unsatisfied (ie. does not match). The length of the pattern doesn't mean *anything whatsoever*

If you need to rank the ordering considering searching for an algorithm and researching the topic *"relevance ranking"*.

Comment: That' possibly might solve my issue ,finding some sort of 'relevancy ranking' seems to be the right direction to go for

Comment: I rolled back the meta discussion. Oh, and thank you ( for the "mean" ;)

Answer (score 0):

there's always not like.

```
    where ic.Column_name like '%address%'
    and ic.Column_name not like '%email%'
```

Comment: Yeah that's if you know the field(s) but what if there are hundreds of fields and you don't know their names ? Also somebody has already come up with that answer here